# Error running a WPF/PRISM app from an ArcGIS desktop add-in button, unable to load modules

Tags: wpf, button, prism, add-in, arcgis

When I tried running a WPF app that uses PRISM from a button add-in in `ArcMap`, the `OnClick` event goes as far as initializing and showing the `Shell.xaml` but when it tries to load the modules and the controls in the regions, I get this error:

> Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'InnerModuleInfoLoader'

The button add-in has this for the `onclick` eventhandler:

```
      protected override void OnClick()
      {
          App app = new App();
          app.InitializeComponent();
          app.Run();
      }
```

In the `App.xaml.cs` then runs the bootstrapper `OnStartUp`:

```
      protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
      {
          base.OnStartup(e);
          Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
          bootstrapper.Run();
      }
```

The modules are copied to the Add-In's `bin\Modules` folder:

```
      protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
      {
          var moduleCatalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog();
          moduleCatalog.ModulePath = @".\Modules";
          return moduleCatalog;
      }
```

The bootstrapper's `Run()` method goes as far as initializing and showing the Shell:

```
      protected override void InitializeShell()
      {
          base.InitializeShell();  
          App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
          App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
      }
```

But on the part where it tries to load the modules and the controls into the regions, I get that error.  The WPF app by itself runs fine, but when the button runs it, it doesn't finish.

I'm not a prism expert, just trying this as a prototype for a next version, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved this issue.  The error message was basically telling me that it doesn't know what "InnerModuleInfoLoader" was, so I tried placing the prism DLLs in the bin folder of the calling app (3rd party button add-in) and voila, it got past through the error message.  We were hoping we did not have to put the DLLs in the GAC or in the 3rd party app/bin folder but I guess we would have to either place them in the GAC or maybe set the path in the EnvironmentVariable for the 3rd party app to find them.